# ElementaryOS: Failed to open connection to "session" message bus

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just installed the latest Elementary OS Freya and did all the updates.

anytime I use the terminal as root, I see this warning message:

> Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Did not receive a
>   reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a
>   reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply
>   timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

I read this is because there are two graphical interfaces conflicting, but that's a little confusing as I'm just running the base configuration without any modifications.

anyone has an idea of how to fix this?